# Expect the unexpected from user

Tags: java

To Validate a user input (numeric field), I wrote a simple method to that, my problem is : I know that the user may enter invalid data in a specific field, so and error is expected from the runtime, now I want to ignore that exception and continue after warning the user.
My method runs perfect but I still receive and error when the exception occurs.
how to avoid displaying that error to the user?
 or if you can support me with a better idea to achieve that.
Thanks

```
   JTextField MyField = In_DataField;
   try {
        int myint = Integer.parseInt(MyField.getText());
   } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
       CustomControls.CustomTools.CustomMsgBox("Enter Valid Number!!");

       // need code here to stop displaying the error message 
enter code here
   }
```

Comment: What error do you get? I suppose your code is a part of some kind of event manager. Please provide the whole method.

Comment: `I still receive and error when the exception occurs` can you elaborate? Do you mean your exception still gets logged?

Comment: Good news, actually the same code (above) now just running without a problem after exit from NetBeans and restating it. I do not know how ? , but everything is ok. Thanks

Comment: I assume you want to erase the message to the user after a while. Please post [mcve] so we don't have to guess how `CustomControls.CustomTools.CustomMsgBox` is implemented.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to suppress exception just comment/remove the line. And to avoid the null pointer exception add the if block as mentioned in my code

But performing the validation is a good one, such as empty and null validations

```
   JTextField MyField = In_DataField;
   try {
        if(MyField == null) {
            MyField = "";
        }
        int myint = Integer.parseInt(MyField.getText());
   } catch(NumberFormatException ex) {
       //CustomControls.CustomTools.CustomMsgBox("Enter Valid Number!!");

       // need code here to stop displaying the error message 

   }
```

Comment: thanks you, but I do control the null in a previous step in my application, my problem is when the user type non-numeric data in the field, ex. ABC while I expect 123 , so this code is doing that, but the catch is throwing an error which is expected as mentioned above.